# when clang compiling to target wasm, it return error for function declaration

Tags: c, linker, clang, webassembly

I have tried to generate `wasm` file from the c program.

clang test.c  --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm -nostartfiles -nostdlib -Wl,--no-entry -Wl,--export-all -o test.wasm

The content of `test.c` the file is as follows

```
extern void __VERIFIER_error(void);
extern void __VERIFIER_assume(int);
void __VERIFIER_assert(int cond) {
  if (!(cond)) {
      ERROR: __VERIFIER_error();
  }
  return;
}
int __VERIFIER_nondet_int();

int test() {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 0;
    while (y < 1000 && __VERIFIER_nondet_int()) {
        x = x + y;
        y = y + 1;
    }
    __VERIFIER_assert(x >= y);
    return 0;
}
```

Encounter the following error message:

```
clang test.c  --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm -nostartfiles -nostdlib -Wl,--no-entry -Wl,--export-all -o test.wasm
wasm-ld: error: /tmp/test-e520f3.o: undefined symbol: __VERIFIER_error
wasm-ld: error: /tmp/test-e520f3.o: undefined symbol: __VERIFIER_nondet_int
clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have updated content of the file as follows:

```
extern "C" void __VERIFIER_error(void);
extern "C" void __VERIFIER_assume(int);
extern "C" void __VERIFIER_assert(int cond) {
  if (!(cond)) {
      ERROR: __VERIFIER_error();
  }
  return;
}
extern "C" int __VERIFIER_nondet_int();

int test() {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 0;
    while (y < 1000 && __VERIFIER_nondet_int()) {
        x = x + y;
        y = y + 1;
    }
    __VERIFIER_assert(x >= y);
    return 0;
}
```

Encounter the following error message, how to get rid of such errors. Can anyone please guide in this regard.

```
test/test.c:1:8: error: expected identifier or '('
extern "C" void __VERIFIER_error(void);
       ^
test/test.c:2:8: error: expected identifier or '('
extern "C" void __VERIFIER_assume(int);
       ^
test/test.c:3:8: error: expected identifier or '('
extern "C" void __VERIFIER_assert(int cond) {
       ^
test/test.c:9:8: error: expected identifier or '('
extern "C" int __VERIFIER_nondet_int();
       ^
test/test.c:13:24: warning: implicit declaration of function '__VERIFIER_nondet_int' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    while (y < 1000 && __VERIFIER_nondet_int()) {
                       ^
test/test.c:17:5: warning: implicit declaration of function '__VERIFIER_assert' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    __VERIFIER_assert(x >= y);
    ^
2 warnings and 4 errors generated.
```

Comment: why these `extern "C" ` ? you are in C, not in C++ for instance. The fact these functions have a name starting by 2 '_' is very suspicious . Where these functions are supposing coming  from, are they defined in a library ? if yes probably you have associated header to include

Comment: Yes, I have defined those functions in file extest.h. Can you please guide me on how to link files using options...I have tried "clang test.c  --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm  --sysroot =/../inlcude/    -nostartfiles -nostdlib -Wl,--no-entry -Wl,--export-all -o test.wasm". I have also tried option --include-directory

Comment: `I have defined those functions in file extest.h` I think you *declared* them, not *defined*, a declaration is just the signature without the body while a definition also has the body. `extern void __VERIFIER_error(void);` and ` void __VERIFIER_error(void);` are declaration, `void __VERIFIER_error(void) { ... }` is a definition, like you defined *test*

Answer (score 0):

You have two functions without definitions. You do not link any libraries or other object files. So linker is not finding them and issues the error message.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to link header files using any option. Let's say all my header files are present in directory /../include. I have tried --sysroot =/../include and --include-directory =/../include options in my command

Comment: 1. "clang test.c --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm --sysroot =/../inlcude/ -nostartfiles -nostdlib -Wl,--no-entry -Wl,--export-all -o test.wasm"

Comment: 2. "clang test.c --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm --include-directory =/../inlcude/ -nostartfiles -nostdlib -Wl,--no-entry -Wl,--export-all -o test.wasm"

Comment: you cant link header files. You can only link object files.

Comment: you need to link object files with the"bodies" of those functions.